# How to convert array of objects into object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert array of objects into a final output of objects. I have an array of objects as mentioned below:

```
[  { "id": "11", "value" : "9999","sample":"1"},
   { "id": "22", "value" : "8888","sample":"2"},
   { "id": "33", "value" : "7777","sample":"3"}
];
```

I need output as below:

```
{
     { "id": "11", "value" : "9999","sample":"1"},
     { "id": "22", "value" : "8888","sample":"2"},
     { "id": "33", "value" : "7777","sample":"3"}
}
```

can anyone help on this ?

Comment: you can't. the second one is not valid without keys.

Comment: your object is not valid in javascript

Comment: An object is a collection of `key: value` pairs. What are the keys supposed to be in your final object?

Comment: Questions on SO should show research and effort: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please don't dump your problem and  wait for a solution. _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ Analyze your problem and ask a specific question. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

Your Object is not valid in javascript. You can do the following:

```js
const arr = [  { "id": "11", "value" : "9999","sample":"1"},
   { "id": "22", "value" : "8888","sample":"2"},
   { "id": "33", "value" : "7777","sample":"3"}
]

const obj = {}
arr.forEach(({id, value, sample}) => {
  obj[id] = {value, sample}
})

console.log(obj)
```